# erro ao importa biblioteca pandas e numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Galera, Estou com um problema para importa a biblioteca panda e o numpy para meu projeto, quando tento executar no pycharm... o seguinte codigo, apresenta-se esse erro:

codigo:

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np
```

erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/moises/Documentos/curso de python/Curso-Ciencia-de-Dados-master/Amostragem/amostragem1.py", line 1, in <module>
 import pandas as pd
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: E esses pacotes estão instalados? Como instalou? Qual a versão do Python que está utilizando?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss eu baixei o anaconda, mas não sei o que fazer. Veio um arquivo com extensão ".sh"(nunca vi essa extensão). Minha versão de pyhton é a 3.7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bom dia amigo,
Pelo que você está relatando o problema não está no pycharm e sim no interpretador do projeto.
Você deve ir em :
*Arquivo(File) -> Configurações(Settings) -> Projeto(project) -> Interpretador(Interpreter)*

Na janela que abrir basta clicar na engrenagem e adicionar o interpretador do Python desejado.
Caso esteja querendo adicionar algum pacote extra basta clicar no ícone do **+** ou no simbolo do anaconda embaixo.

Veja se com estas alterações resolvem seu problema.

Abraços.

[image: Imagem]

Comment: Muito bom o que voce mandou. Mas agora, não dá, o mesmo erro. Na verdade não dá nenhum erro. No terminal do Pycharm, retorna essa expressão: "Process finished with exit code 0". Tendo na primeira linha do meu código a importação do pandas 'import pandas as pd'. Inclui nesse projeto, como vc orientou os pacotes, manualmente o pandas e o numpy, mas agora entendo que ele não esta interpretando o código.

Comment: @MoisesMoraes a mensagem são apenas informações adicionais fornecidas pelo console do IDE. O script está executando como esperado. Dizer que o processo terminou com o código de saída 0 significa que tudo funcionou bem. Mas caso queira ver se as bibliotecas estão importando correto tente importar pelo shell do python presente no próprio pycharm e veja se ele consegue realizar a importação desses pacotes.

Answer (score 2):

Um meio de descobrir qual é o problema é primeiramente saber se você tem esses módulos instalados.

Primeiramente utilize o comando:

```
$ pip3 list
```

Esse comando irá listar todos os módulos instalados na sua máquina.

Você deve agora pesquisar na lista se existe esses módulos, eles estarão descritos com o mesmo nome `numpy` e `pandas`.

Caso não encontre execute o comando:

```
$ pip3 install numpy && pip3 install pandas
```

Feito isso, verifique se o problema irá persistir.

Comment: Não encontrei eles na listagem como você indicou. Então instalei, conforme orientado, mas o erro ainda continua. Alguma dica? E obrigado por me responder!

Comment: @MoisesMoraes, quando você importa pelo terminal tambem ocorre esse erro ou só no pycharm?

Comment: Só esta dando erro no pycharm e no spyder( que estou tentando também, mas sem sucesso). No terminal funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: @MoisesMoraes, já tentou reinstalar esses programas e ver no que dá?

Comment: Já tentei o spyder, mas o pycharm não!

Comment: tente entao! :)

Comment: WhoisMatt, já tentei o erro persisti!

Comment: O erro está no pycharm... Vou procurar algo e te aviso caso encontrar

Comment: Blz! Vou ver o que faço.